# Add horizontal scroll bar when viewport is narrower for any block level element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used to use bootstrap '.responsive-table' class to add a horizontal scroll bar when screen size is less than 768px;

This is the bootstrap way of doing this, but it only intends to apply on tables.

```
.table-responsive {
  @media screen and (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: (@line-height-computed * 0.75);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid @table-border-color;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Let's say I have a div, or a `<ul>` tag,

```
<div class="foo" style="width:980px">
/*content here is 980px width*/
</div>
```

How to make the scroll bar appear on div.foo on a page with bootstrap loaded, when the screen size is smaller then 980px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css should help

```
div.foo {
    min-width: 980px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This will not let the width of div.foo go below 980px. It it goes then it will display a scrollbar.